# twitter bootstrap dropdown with horizontal scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

I am using twitter bootstrap dropdown ,but I cant get the horizontal scroll to work.
I have tried

```
overflow-x:scroll;
```

and

```
overflow-x:visible;
```

**CSS**

```
.md-size-list{
width:70px;
padding:0px;
overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control 
        md-size-list" id="component" size="6">
  <option>Name</option>
  <option>Name1200</option>
  <option>Name1200</option>
  <option>Name1200</option>
  <option>Name1200</option>
  <option>Name1200</option>
  <option>Name1200</option>
</select>
```

Here is the [example](http://www.bootply.com/115612)

Comment: possible duplicate of [horizontal scroll bar in select box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917824/horizontal-scroll-bar-in-select-box)

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to wrap your dropdown around a `div` tag and apply the CSS to it:

```
<div class="md-size-list">
    <select multiple="multiple" "form-control" id="component" size="6">
      <option>Name</option>
      <option>Name1200</option>
      <option>Name1200</option>
      <option>Name1200</option>
      <option>Name1200</option>
      <option>Name1200</option>
      <option>Name1200</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HDUVr/)</kbd>

Comment: ..@meda..thanks,it works fine..but it is affecting UI look and feel..Any method by which the list itself adds scroll if the element is too long.....

Comment: @user2954936 you have 70px as width make it larger like 100px, and if element is longer the scrollbar will show

Comment: display: inline-block; display: inline;