# Horizontal scrollbar not working on select tag in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The horizontal scrollbar is not working on a select tag in Internet Explorer.

Example:

```
<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 250px; overflow-x: auto">
  <option value="4">Option 1</option>
  <option value="4">Option 2</option>
  <option value="4">Veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeryyyy Long Option</option>
  <option value="4">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Internet Explorer:

[image: Internet Explorer]

How can I make the select tag horizontally scrollable in IE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [horizontal scroll bar in select box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917824/horizontal-scroll-bar-in-select-box)

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
select{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

select:hover{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

granted, the user will not seee the scroll bar until the element is hovered.

Comment: try `-ms-overflow-x:`

Comment: What value for -ms-overflow-x?

Comment: it accepts hidden, scroll, or auto. I would try auto or scroll.

Comment: Depending on the version of IE then there are two other things that could be wrong that I can think of. Either overflow does not work in the `<select>` tags. Try to set something up similar with only `<div>` tags instead of `<select>` and `<option>` tags to see if you can get it to behave in that environment, if so then overflow on `<select>` might be limited by that version of IE. Otherwise, the only other thing I could think of is your DOCTYPE isn't playing nice with that version of IE.

Answer (score 0):

put it in a div and style it:

```
<div style="width: 250px; overflow-x:scroll;">
<select multiple="multiple" >
     <option value="4">Option 1</option>
     <option value="4">Option 2</option>
     <option value="4">Veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeryyyy Long Option</option>
     <option value="4">Option 3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Select tag will have own verticall scroll if it contains many items and this scrollbar will not be visible if option has a long text